# Prove that $T(n)=\omega(n)$?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, trees, recursion, big-o-notation

**Edit: can someone provide clear answer with all details**

Given:

$T(n)=T(n/10)+T(an)+n$ while $a$ is a const and $T(n)=1:(n<10)$

I was asked to find the minimum value for $a$ for which $T(n)=\omega(n)$

Using a set of complicated equations I found and proved that $a=9/10$ is the correct answer (for sure)

But how I can prove that using recursion tree?

Here I did all of the calculations:

[image]

Comment: Please Note: the tree doesn't end here, I just wrote the first rows to understand

Comment: You need to obtain both a lower-bound and an upper-bound for the number of operations. For the lower-bound, find 1) the depth of the **shortest** branch and 2) the number of operations for each level before that. Note that up to this depth all levels are full, so you can sum the number up to this level as per your picture. For the upper-bound, you find 1) the depth of the **longest** branch 2) an upper-bound on the number of operations for each level. Note that you can use $n (\frac 1{10} + \alpha)^k$ as an upper bound (the actual value is smaller since some branches halt earlier).

Comment: Why I care about upper bound? I only need the lower right? plus how may I know which one is smaller?

Comment: "I was asked to find the **minimum** value for a for which T(n)=ω(n)". How do you know that the value is the smallest otherwise? By having a matching upper- and lower-bounds, you prove this. "plus how may I know which one is smaller?" Which *what* is smaller?

Comment: I refer to which depth is smaller, as u can see I found two depths. It will be cool if you can submit an answer with some more details since still I'm not convinced I need higher bound

Comment: It's easy to show that $\alpha$ must be greater than $\frac 1 {10}$: for $\alpha = \frac 1 {10}$ you can use Master's theorem, and for lesser $\alpha$ you have lesser $T(n)$. Therefore, $\log_{10} n < \log_{\frac 1 \alpha} n$. (also, it doesn't actually matter which one is smaller: after all, both $\log {10}$ and $\log \frac 1 {\alpha}$ are constants and $\log_c n = \frac {\log n} {\log c}$)

Comment: "It's easy to show that  must be greater than 1/10". why is that?

Comment: I proved everything but this one, how can I prove that a must me greater than 1/10 (I don't care if it can be equal to it)